# How to integrate Ranorex and Parasoft SOAtest?

Tags: c#, automation, ranorex, parasoft

I have a task to start Parasoft SOAtest from Ranorex for doing some Web Services testing through SOAtest. How to Start and use SOAtest from Ranorex. I'm using C# as my scripting language.

Comment: why do you want to do this? can you not use soatest separately? Could you please elaborate the business reasoning behind this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a Parasoft SOA test using soatestcli.exe.

Location of executable: "C:\Program Files\Parasoft\SOAtest\9.6\soatestcli.exe"

It requires the below Arguments:
-data "Project Workspace"
-config "user://configfile"
-resource "test.tst"
-report "reportLocation.html"

Example: 
Open your command prompt and enter:
"C:\Program Files\Parasoft\SOAtest\9.6\soatestcli.exe" -Data "Project Workspace" -config "user://configfile" -resource "test.tst" -report "reportLocation.html"

This makes it so you can run it from C# or whatever other automation tool you use.

Hope that helps or at least gives you a good start. :)